# Uploading product image not showing on front end

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, magento-community

I have a Magento 1.9.1.0 CE site that was just installed on a Cpanel VPS. Our issue is the site is working fine all except when we go to replace a product image we go to the Magento admin page for a specific product and upload an image using the images tab section in the products admin page. The image gets uploaded and when I move my mouse over it I can see the image just fine.

However, if I now look at the product on the front end of the website the image is just showing the gray Magento logo type image and not the image I uploaded. I also can view the source on the front-end and see the URL for the image is
http://www.******.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x608.191808192/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/v/h/newimag.jpg and if I go to that location on the server I do not see the image newimag.jpg  ?? So it seems to not really be fully uploaded and I am not sure why.

I made sure all the media and sub directories have a permission of 0777 
I cleared the Magento cache and re-indexed |
I cleared my browser cache

I am not sure what else to do to fix it.
When I view the console in Google Chrome I see the below message

coolsocks_multipack:63 Uncaught TypeError: Product.ConfigurableSwatches is not a constructor

---

**The entire directory path exsists but the image does not seem to be making it into the folder? So in my above example url http://www.******.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x608.191808192/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/v/h/ I do not see the image named newimag.jpg  .**

Comment: is directory /media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/ exists ? which part of the full path to the image on filesystem does not exist ?

Answer (score 1):

take a look in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php` file in the `uploadAction` function of `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_GalleryController` class, if you debug there you should figure out why the final file is not written into destination:

```
        ...
        $result = $uploader->save(
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseTmpMediaPath()
        );
        ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it is a permission issue, follow this link to set the correct permission 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/121518)